# Remove a specific part of string split by multiple-charater delimiter in bash

Tags: regex, string, bash

I'm trying to process my string and steps as below:

```
mytext='\\[[123 one (/)\n\\[[456 two (/)\n\\[[789 three (/)'
myvar=456
```

And I want to remove a part of string (and delimiter) that match `myvar` after split by delimiter `\n`, the result should be

> `\\[[123 one (/)\n\\[[789 three (/)`

But I still not find out the solution.

If the delimiter is a single character like `:`, I can be done with sed command:

```
mytext2='\\[[123 one (/):\\[[456 two (/):\\[[789 three (/)'
myvar2=456
echo $mytext2 | sed -E "s/[^:]*${myvar}[^:]*(:|$)//g"
```

> `Result as expected: \\[[123 one (/):\\[[789 three (/)`

How can be done if delimiter is a multiple-character in this case?
Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your Q to include a version of `$mytext` that includes the `\n` chars as needed and the output from running your cmd thru sed. Also try `echo -e "$mytext" | ...` . Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you use `sed -E`, you still lack some support (`?<=`, `?!`, `?=`, `?` etc). I suggest you use `perl` (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions).

```
mytext='\\[[123 one (/)\n\\[[456 two (/)\n\\[[789 three (/)';
myvar=456;
echo $mytext | perl -pe "s/(?<=\\\n).*${myvar}.*?(\\\n|$)//g";
```

**Details**:

- `(?<=\\\n)`: string starts after `\n`. `\\` escape character `\`
- `.*${myvar}.*?(\\\n|$)`: get string which contains value of variable `myvar` and ends with `\n` or `end of line`.

Result.

```
\\[[123 one (/)\n\\[[789 three (/)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can find another delimiter to be used for example, `:`, you can first replace it with `:`,

```
echo $mytext | tr '\n' ':' | sed -E "s/[^:]*${myvar}[^:]*(:|$)//g"
```

The full script looks like this

```
mytext='\\[[123 one (/):\\[[456 two (/):\\[[789 three (/)'
myvar=456
v=$(echo $mytext | tr '\n' ':' | sed -E "s/[^:]*${myvar}[^:]*(:|$)//g")
echo $v
```

If the multiple character delimiter is something like `abcd`, you can try to use `sed` to replace it first instead of using `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

I sugges `awk` in this case since you may specify the literal multichar delimiter pattern as the input/output field separator, iterate over the fields and discard all those not matching your value:

```
mytext='\\[[123 one (/)\n\\[[456 two (/)\n\\[[789 three (/)'
myvar=456
awk -v myvar=$myvar 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\\\\n"} {s="";
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { 
        if ($i !~ myvar) {s = s (i==1 ? "" : OFS) $i;}
    }
} END{print s}' <<< "$mytext"
# => \\[[123 one (/)\\n\\[[789 three (/)
```

See the [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/NW3XEe).

**NOTES**:

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\\\\n"}` - sets the input/output field separator to `\n`
- `-v myvar=$myvar` passes the `myvar` to `awk`
- `s=""` - assigns `s` to an empty string
- `for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {...}` - iterates over all fields
- `if ($i !~ myvar) {...}` - if the current field value matches `myvar`...
- `s = s (i==1 ? "" : OFS) $i;}` - append either the current field value to `s` (if is the first field) or output separator and the current field value (if it is not the first)
- `END{print s}` - prints `s` after the field checks.